# configure command error (arch is not supported)

Tags: linux, configure

I've recently downloaded a library, but I'm having trouble compiling it. When i try to run "configure" in the root directory, i get this output:

```
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
```

However, compilation prosecutes until I get this error:

```
**configure: error: ARCH  is not supported**
```

I tried googling the second error, but found nothing. Could someone help me ?

Comment: What library, what distribution are you using? And most important, what command line options are you using when calling `configure`?

Comment: My distribution is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, the library is Polylib. I'm not using any option with configure. I think in this case a manual installation was the only possiblity, and followed the instructions provided by the library guide itself.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ubuntu, so I don't know if it installs c-development packages by default. But I assume you have gotten c compilation up and running. When it comes to Polylib, it looks like the latest release (5.22.5) is old as dirt. Have you tried the git version? It has six more years of development. (In addition to `git`, You will have to install all the autotools packages). After cloning the git-repository, you will have to run `./autogen.sh` to generate the `configure` script before runnning it.

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue with Polylib 5.22.5 on Fedora 28 x86_64. State the version of the library you are using and provide a download link. State the operating system and version you are using. Show your `config.log`. You may have to put `config.log` on Pastebin.

Comment: Hello! If you were able to tell us, step-by-step, how you are trying to make this work, we might be able to better help point you in the right direction!